# How to install PFX certificate?

Tags: 19.04, certificates

Okay, I have PFX certificate. I need to install it to my Ubuntu 19.04 to have access to other resource by Cisco.

I received PFX certificate from my customer & I need to have connection to his servers for deploy apps. They mind all their contractors have Windows & than generate PFX certificates for them.

I use Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobitily Client to access its servers by VPN.

How to do it?

Comment: What's the PFX for?  What Cisco resource needs this?  We need more details to provide you an accurate answer.

Comment: added more details

Comment: So this PFX contains... what?  A user certificate?  A VPN certificate?  We need **more details** to understand the use case for the PFX.  PFX can contain a certificate, a cert authority cert, and a cert privkey for a user cert at most, or a whole chain of certificates embedded in it, so it's still unclear what's in the PFX and why it's needed.

Comment: Yes, it contains user certificate.

Comment: And this user certificate is to be used with websites and internal web-based admin panels and such?  Or is this going to be utilized by something else such as scripts or specialized utilities?  (I've written an answer that explains installing the cert within Chrome/Chromium and Firefox for now)

Answer (score 15):

Per your comments, the PFX file contains a User Certificate and Private Key.

**To install this is going to depend on what you are using to access the resources.**  *Usually* these certificates end up being used for SSL Client Auth on websites, in which case you will need to import the PFX file in your browser.

In Chrome/Chromium, you enter your "Settings" page, type in "Certificates" in the search bar, choose "Manage Certificates", and under the "Your Certificates" tab, hit "Import", select the PFX, and use the Import Password to import the PFX file.  Chrome/Chromium will then be able to use your certificates.  (HOWEVER you have to do this for each browser independently.)

In Firefox, open "Preferences", in the "Find in Preferences" search bar type in 'Certificates', then you'll see a button that says "View Certificates".  Click it to open Firefox's Certificate Manager.  Make sure you're on the "Your Certificates" tab, and then click 'Import', find the PFX on disk, and use the PFX import password to authorize the import.

***Note that you need to do this individually for each browser on-system, and this answer does NOT include all browsers in the universe in the answer - it only covers the most common three.***

Comment: Firefox seems  not to recognize the .pfx file but I managed to install it on Chromium.

Comment: @fccoelho Firefox may want a .p12 file which is pretty much the same.  This said, Firefox is also picky with the format, so it might not work if any part of it is malformed or 'odd'.

Answer (score 2):

To connect to the VPN via Cisco AnyConnect on linux using a pfx file containing a certificate and a private key, you must first convert the pfx file into a certificate `*.pem` and a key `*.key` using commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.pem -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.key -nocerts
```

and then put them to directories `/opt/.cisco/certificates/client/` and `/opt/.cisco/certificates/client/private/` respectively and restart the client.

Comment: Amazing answer.. This is exactly what I need. Works well!